# How to get version of application for .Net Core on Linux

Tags: .net, linux, version, .net-core

I am trying to get the version of my application that is running built on .Net Core but --version does not work nor does -v.

Im struggling to find some sort of guide as to implementing this on the linux side of things.

Comment: I assume you'd have to implement this in your application would you not? Isn't `--version` just a command line argument?

Comment: Thats what I thought too, but wasnt sure since --version seems to be super common in the linux environment. Seemed like it might be something that I needed to wire up.

Comment: I'm not a Linux guru but I think it's super common because it's generally accepted that if you're writing a Linux application, you wire up `--version`. Same for `/help` or similar. I could be completely wrong though.

Comment: If you come from Linux background you should notice that currently .NET Core is still on the fence between Windows  and Linux. It just starts to support Linux, so more native integration would only come in a future release. Of course, you can parse the parameters and process it on your own.

Comment: So i added the argument handling and it still isnt recognizing it. There must be something different i need to do?

Comment: Many Java applications in Linux does not provide it unless they are built as CLI applications.